# Fastest Way to Compare a cell in multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 sheets and 1 "base" sheet. I want to compare the value of `Range("A1").value` in "base" sheet with the other 10 sheets (same cell as base). What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this? Thanks,

Comment: There isn't the fastest and most efficient way.. There are just too many ways... What have you tried and how does your code not do what you would like it to do?

Comment: I just need a "good algorithm" to accomplish this. I don't want code to be written for me, I just need an idea. Thanks,

Comment: How do you currently compare it? What are your circumstances? Why do you need to compare it to all different sheets, what do you do when there is a match, what do you do when there is no match? I mean all these questions should have been answered in your original question to give us some kind of background about how you arrived at your question.... we are not wizards nor mind readers here...

Comment: @Grendizer you need to create a loop with sheets and a procedure which compares base sheet with other one and stores results somewhere.

Comment: The "base" sheet will contain Greek text from "Main" source. The other sheets will contain Greek text, from different sources, that "should" be identical to the Main source. If I find differences, then I will run a specific code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short sub procedure.

```
Sub base_test()
    Dim w As Long
    For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If LCase(Sheets(w).Name) <> "base" Then
            If Sheets(w).Range("A1") = Sheets("Base").Range("A1") Then
                'do something
            End If
        End If
    Next w
End Sub
```

I prefer this method as it does not rely upon an `On Error Resume Next`.